# BizTalk MSMQ Adapter: Issue reading from remote private queue

Tags: biztalk, msmq

I am experiencing an issue with a MSMQ receive location setup in BizTalk. I am looking for ideas on resolution. Your help in this regard is much appreciated!

Here is the setup:

**BizTalk Server – Windows Server 2012 - Hosted on a domain**

a) The MSMQ Receive location points to a remote private queue

b)  BizTalk MSMQ host instance runs under a domain account

**Server hosting MSMQ – Windows Server 2008 R2 - Not on domain**

a) Setup a private transactional and non-transactional queue

b) Provided Everyone, Anonymous, and Network Service users full control over both queues
c) Created a shadow account, bthost.instance, with the same password to determine if that resolves the issue

Here are some of the steps I used to troubleshoot:

1. When I enable the receive location within BizTalk, I receive an error stating that **“The user does not have permissions to receive messages. Please check the queue permissions. "**
2. I am able to send successfully to a queue hosted on the MSMQ Server. However, MSMQ uses different protocols for receive (RPC) and send (TCP). I believe this explains the discrepancy.
3. I am able to receive successfully from a queue that is hosted on another server that is on the domain. I am encountering issues with queues hosted on a server that is not on the domain.
4. I have followed directions from the following [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2010/03/24/understanding-how-msmq-security-blocks-rpc-traffic.aspx). I have ensured DTC is configured appropriately, windows firewall exceptions have been set for Message Queuing and Cleared the ‘Disable un-authenticated RPC calls’ from the Message Queuing Server Security settings from Computer Management (both on the BizTalk and server that hosts the message queue)
5. **Based on the following [Technet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771268%28v=ws.10%29.aspx),** Added a registry setting HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSMQ\Parameters\Security\NewRemoteReadServerAllowNoneSecurityClient and set it to 1
6. Tested with both TCP:IP address and OS:Server Name conventions.** Both convention results in the same error above. FORMATNAME:DIRECT=TCP:xxx.xx.x.xx\PRIVATE$\QueueName and FORMATNAME:DIRECT=OS:ServerName\PRIVATE$\QueueName
7. I wrote a C# console program to read from the same transactional queue. I executed the console program from the BizTalk server. I noticed that I was able to read from the queue using my AD credentials. However, I was unable to read using the BizTalk host credentials. I am receiving a "Access to message queuing system is denied".

We have an option to set username/password in the receive location from BizTalk. I used my domain credentials and got the same error. My hunch is that the BizTalk host credentials are probably still being used to initiate the RPC call.

Comment: If you run the console app from the biztalk server, but use the biztalk service credentials (shif + right click -> run as other user) does the console app work?

Comment: What permissions does your AD user have that the Host Instance run-user doesn't?